# Why does my variable need a 'var' declaration, when it's already inside a var declaration?

Tags: javascript, variables

If a mod can help me phrase my question better, I'd appreciate it because it's hard to ask this without simply providing an example. Here is a function that I've created:

```
$("#myField").on('keyup', function(event){
    var input = $(this), 
         val  = input.val(),
         inputGroup = input.parents('div.input-group')
         searchingIcon = $(inputGroup).find('i.auto-spinner'),
         button = $(inputGroup).find('span.input-group-btn > button.btn'),
         key = event.which,
         typingTimer; // This throws an error typingTimer is not defined

    //Clear typing timeout on keypress
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    //.... more code below.. not important
  });
```

As you can see, I like to declare my vars in one simple var declaration followed by commas, however, in this case when I get to typingTimer, I get a undefined var error, as though it's looking for the variable, instead of defining an empty variable. If I simply change things to this:

```
$("#myField").on('keyup', function(event){
    var input = $(this), 
         val  = input.val(),
         inputGroup = input.parents('div.input-group')
         searchingIcon = $(inputGroup).find('i.auto-spinner'),
         button = $(inputGroup).find('span.input-group-btn > button.btn'),
         key = event.which;
   var typingTimer; // All is well again...

    //Clear typing timeout on keypress
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    //.... more code below.. not important
  });
```

Everything will work fine. This isn't the first time I've come across this phenomenon, and I don't really know the cause for it. Are there some limitations on how I can define variables not separated by (;)?

Comment: You are missing a comma after your `inputGroup` declaration, causing an automatic semicolon after that line. Thus, all subsequent assignments are not declarations; they are simply assignments to existing variables (or to implicit globals if no variable of that name exists). I'm not sure whether to close this as a typo, or answer it because others may make this same typo?

Comment: _"This isn't the first time I've come across this phenomenon"_: perhaps time for a change in how your declare your vars then?

Comment: Indeed. It's not a phenomenon, it's  incorrect code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a comma after one of your declarations `inputGroup = input.parents('div.input-group')`. Since all of your other declarations are also an expression (they have an = sign after them), they're valid statements on their own (assigning the result to a global variable). `typingTimer` doesn't have such an assignment, though, so it's causing the undefined error.

Adding the missing comma will fix the problem.

Comment: Ah that has to be it. I will have to go back and check my other instances, but it's probably the same thing. Where I have long var declarations.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma after your `inputGroup` declaration, causing an automatic semicolon after that line. Thus, all subsequent assignments are not declarations; they are simply assignments..

We can illustrate the problem with your code more clearly by explicitly writing the implicit semicolon:

```
// declarations
var input = $(this), 
     val  = input.val(),
     inputGroup = input.parents('div.input-group');

// merely assignments
     searchingIcon = $(inputGroup).find('i.auto-spinner'),
     button = $(inputGroup).find('span.input-group-btn > button.btn'),
     key = event.which,
     typingTimer;
```

`typingTimer` does not exist, so using it in any way outside of the left-hand side of an assignment is invalid. The other assignment statements above are acceptable because they create implicit globals (since you are not in strict mode).

If you add a comma after the assignment of `inputGroup`, then the subsequent lines are declarations, as you expect.

Comment: I think you meant `inputGroup = input.parents('div.input-group'),` or at least a var before `searchingIcon`

Comment: @LCIII In the code block, I meant to illustrate the problem more clearly with an equivalent problematic example, not provide a solution. Edited for clarity.